# new video card: Geforce GTX 1050 Ti -- can't see bios hdmi (Ubuntu 20.10)

Tags: boot, nvidia, hdmi

I can't see the bios through this card on hdmi.
The only way login and see the display is through VNC viewer, where all looks fine.  BUT when I logout, I see black screen and cannot login.

Doing a bit of investigating shows:

```
sudo lshw -c display
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:2d:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:119 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
```

So how can I correct this issue.  I thought about booting from a memory stick and attempting reinstall, but again, since I can't see the bios, I can't select the usb to boot.

ANY thoughts?
I have searched around and it seems like this may be a fairly common problem.

Comment: Accessing your BIOS has nothing to do with Ubuntu (or any other operating system).  The BIOS menu is a function of your hardware and is loaded before any bootloader.  You should consult your motherboard's documentation.

Comment: see the solution below,  it was the display driver and the OLED display.  And given the number of large OLED displays now, I suspect that others will have this issue, so I don't believe this question should have been down graded.

Comment: I didn't downvote this question, but it still doesn't make sense to me.   How does this have anything to do with your BIOS? As mentioned before, your BIOS settings are available when you first start the PC **before** any drivers or anything to do with the OS is loaded. Are you sure your *question* is accurate about the nature of the original problem?  FYI: please don't edit your question and add "SOLVED" to the title. When someone else posts an answer you can click the check mark to accept it. When you post your own answer you can come back in a few days and accept your own.

Comment: good comment, nothing to do with the bios directly other than default video too quick for my oled display.

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me was the video card and my monitor an LG Oled 65 in display.  When the login display attempted to display, the speed was too high and no sync.

So the solution, was to login through VNC viewer and set the display settings to what worked well.  THEN do:

This Solved my Issuue:

Go into Settings > Devices > Displays and configure your monitors the way you want for your login screen (in your case, internal laptop display disabled). Click the "Save" button when done.

Copy your user's monitors.xml file into the home folder for gdm user.

To copy the monitors.xml file, open a terminal and perform the following:

sudo cp ~/.config/monitors.xml ~gdm/.config/monitors.xml
sudo chown gdm:gdm ~gdm/.config/monitors.xml

ALL now his fine.  I suspect that there is an easier setting to just control the hz of the display, but this works well for me.